# Best solution to delivery binary (and sometime big) files by WebServices

Tags: web-services, stream

I have an application that consumes Rest WebServices that delivery instant binary content (reports in pdf or xls). I Would like to know if is this the best solution or should i just generate the reports and deliver an absolute path that is referencing them?

Both are possible alternatives because this WebServices are called for first by a Web Application, handled and then passed to the client. Which one is the best choice to deliver the report download?

Thank you.